# which dependency injection framework should I choose

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I am working on a web project using velocity template and servlets. The code is a bit old and we are trying to refactor it before adding new functionalities. I am thinking of introducing dependency injection framework. Searching on net, I found spring DI, pico, guice as some of the options. But, not sure which is the right option. Ideally, I am looking for something easy to start with and lightweight.

Comment: Guice is lighter weight than Spring.  Spring is more than a DI framework.  I don't know anything about pico.

Comment: consider moving to programmers site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering it is "a web project using velocity template and servlets", I suggest [springframework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework). It is well [documented](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/), vastly used/tested, active community and will help with more then DI.